# Design SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, graphics

[image: Original app screenshot]

This is the view of Scanner activity. I am using `SurfaceView` and an image button with a 48dip png image icon. I want to design it more. It may not be upto the level of the second screenshot which is of SuperBeam app.

[image: Super Beam App screenshot]

Here is the xml code of my Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.abhayjatindoshi.encryptorcode.qrlogin.Scanner">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dip"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scanImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_48dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/camera_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand the design to create your layout.

Put your surface view also in frame layout i forget to add it.

[image]

Comment: how can i put linear layout on top of a `SurfaceView` or maybe another `LinearLayout`.... and what about the red blur line on the middle which keeps going up and down

Comment: i completely understood the design. Can you please help me with xml coding.

Comment: we can use `FrameLayout` and then place other Layouts one after the other. To place one over other you can give `fill_parent` for width and height which will fill the whole screen.

Comment: @Encryptor  yes you can use.just remember you framelayout is for place thing on each other as layers.